# An error occurred while extracting files (following gpg decription of a .gpg file to a .dump file)

Tags: postgresql, gnupg, ubuntu-20.04

I have a postgres database backed up, encrypted, and saved as a `.gpg` file. I'm struggling to extract/use the .dump file.

I've initially tried decrypting it with this command:

```
gpg --decrypt --output /home/jimmythecode/Downloads/db_backup /home/jimmythecode/Downloads/heroku-backup-2022-05-05_07.00.gpg
```

`gpg` seems to have accepted my encryption passphrase/secret and has created a compressed `db_backup` file in my downloads folder - but when I open and try to extract the `pg_backup.dump` contained within the `db_backup` file I get the error: `An error occurred while extracting files`.

I've ran the command `file db_backup` in my terminal. It returns:

```
db_backup: gzip compressed data, was "pg_backup.dump", last modified: Thu May  5 07:00:35 2022, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 332380
```

So, since it's a `gzip` file, I've tried using the command: `gunzip db_backup`. But this returns:

```
gzip: db_backup: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

If I try entering the commands `gunzip db_backup.gzip` or `gunzip db_backup.gz` I get:

```
gzip: db_backup.gz: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I never found out if the above is possible. I've found an alternative, which is to create a .SQL rather than a .dump file:

```
gpg --batch --yes --passphrase=<MY PASSPHRASE> -d /home/jimmythecode/Downloads/heroku-backup-2022-05-05_07.00.gpg | gunzip --to-stdout > backup.sql
```

I then created a database called `june30test` and executed the following line in my terminal:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d june30test -1 /home/jimmythecode/Downloads/backup.sql -x --no-owner
```

The database is now restored.